# Elastic search, most efficient filter for boolean mapping, ie select all true/false

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following field mapping:

```
mapping.add_property(BooleanField(name='my_bool'))
```

I want to return all the items where this field is true/false and am currently doing this with a term filter.  Is there are more efficient way to structure this filter?

Thanks.

```
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "my_bool" : "true"}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using a [term filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-filter.html)  would be  more efficient in this

1) a query involves calculating [scores](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/relevance-intro.html) for documents which is not relevant for the above case.

2) a term filter would iterate over all documents building a bitset which is then cached for subsequent queries

```
{
     "filter" : {
          "term" : {"my_bool" : "true"}
      }

}
```